# How to resolve the com_exception error in php which occurs in reload (reading barcodes from images)?

Tags: php, com

I am using clear image SDK for reading barcode from images. The code is working only first time on my browser. When I reload the page, it throws an exception. To make it work again, I restart my web server and it works again. But when I reload the page, it again throws the same exception. The error is given below:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> ClearImage.ClearImage.1<br/><b>Description:</b> SEH Exception 0xC0000005' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 11
( ! ) com_exception: <b>Source:</b> ClearImage.ClearImage.1<br/><b>Description:</b> SEH Exception 0xC0000005 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 11
```

If I call the script from command line, it works fine and it does not matter if I call the script again. I dont need to restart the webserver at all.

What is exactly going on with this script? Do I need to close any particular resources or connections in the script so that it can work again? This is the first time I am working with COM object.

```
<?php
try {
    // To insert line breaks in HTML output replace \n with <br>
    // Create and Configure ClearImage Object
    $Ci = new COM("ClearImage.ClearImage");
} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
// Create the 1D Barcode Pro object. Use any of the other engines here.
$Bc = $Ci->CreateBarcodePro();
// Open file.
$File = 'c39.tif'; // Use YOUR file name

$File = 'C:\\test.jpg';
$Bc->Image->Open($File);
// $Bc->Code39 = true;
// Set reading parameters. Update values if needed. See Online API help
$Bc->AutoDetect1D = 65535;

/*
 * my testing
 */
$Bc->Type = 2;

$Bc->Directions = 2;
$Bc->Algorithm = 2;
/*
 * my tesing
 */
$Bc->Algorithm = 2;

// Read Barcodes
$BCcount = $Bc->Find(0);
echo "\nBarcodes: $BCcount\n";
if ($BCcount == 0) {
    $Msg = "No barcodes found in $File \n";
    exit($Msg);
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $BCcount; $i ++) {
    echo "Barcode #$i ";
    $FBc = $Bc->BarCodes($i);
    // NOTE: Text value will terminate on the first null in data
    echo "Type: $FBc->Type Length: $FBc->Length\n";
    echo "Barcode Value: $FBc->Text \n";
    echo " Binary Data in Hex: \n ";
    $hex_ary = array();
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($FBc->Data as $chr) {
        $hex_ary[] = sprintf("%02X", $chr);
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
        if ($cnt == 16)         // break lines after 16 numbers
{
            $hex_ary[] = sprintf("\n");
            $cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    echo implode(' ', $hex_ary);
    echo "\n";
}

unset($Ci);
```

Comment: Which line is line 11? That error code cited in there means *access violation* which is accessing memory via a null or invalid pointer. May it be that some of the references stored in the page get reset or invalidated when you reload the page?

Comment: it should be $Bc = $Ci->CreateBarcodePro();